# Is it possible to call a function over and over but to not reset its previous values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, canvas

So I am creating a flappy bird game (If you understand what this game is it would make it much easier for you to understand what I am about to say) and inside this game I have 2 pipes. One of the pipes is located at the lowest y value(600px) and one starts at a y value of 0. So these pipes essentially have opposite y values but the same X values(the X value also moves, but they are still the same value of X). The height of the pipes are also randomly generated. **Question starts here:** what I want for this code is after a number of tubeX pixels traveled ( a time interval could also work), I want to add another set of pipes and do the same with that value. But the values of the old pipes must stay the same. I think an array of some sort would be best but my javascript coding abilities are quite low and would have not a clue how to implement something like that into my code until I see it.

This bit of code generates random heights:

```
function pipeY()    {
     var top = Math.random() * -32 + 1;
      height1 = top * 10;
     var bottom = Math.random() * 32 + 1;
      height2 = bottom *10 
      loop();
      }
```

this creates a moving X value for the pipes:

```
tubeX = 400;
velocityX = 0;
force = -0.5;
function pipeX()    {  
    velocityX += force;
    velocityX *= 0.9;
    tubeX += velocityX;
 }
```

This creates the two pipes that are opposite of each other:

```
function show()  {
     var tubeHeight1 = 600;
     var tubeHeight2 = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
   tube1 = ctx.fillRect(tubeX,tubeHeight1,5,height1);
   tube2 = ctx.fillRect(tubeX,tubeHeight2,5,height2);
    ctx.stroke();
   }
```

Comment: You just need separate instances of your pipe, so when you do `tubeX += velocityX` you're just affecting *that instance*. The next pipe has its own value of `tubeX`.

Comment: Yea when I was experiment with some code I think I saw that the pipes were stacking up on top of each other after n number of pixels but I was not to sure.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] if you want help with that

Comment: Check out [Javascript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) which allow you to store both functions and variables in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a while loop inside the pipeX() function. I also changed the values of tubeX to 800 so it just creates a new pipe more efficiently at 400 px. This probably is not the most efficient way but it looks good!

```
function pipeX() {
var lastTime = 0;
velocityX += force;
velocityX *= 0.9;
tubeX += velocityX;

while (tubeX < -25) {
 show();
 if (tubeX = 400)    {
     new pipeY();
     new show();
     }
   }
}
```